# How to programmatically enter password on encrypted pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I will open the pdf on iframe. PDF is encrypted to disable printing.
User will enter the password of pdf but i want to do this progmatically. 
Is there a way to enter the password without decrypting or creating new pdf?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  It appears to me that you have an encrypted PDF that has both a view password and an edit password.  Currently you are loading the PDF in an iframe and the users have to put in the view password.  You want to enter the view password with the program so users may view the pdf uninterrupted, but still maintain the encrypted permissions.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes exactly, but i figure it out this today, I just need to left the user password blank on encryption and with owner password. So that the user will not need to enter the password to view files and the print option is still disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an opensource pdf library called PDFSharp:

http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/

You can use this library in your project to programatically open the encrypted pdf file.

Comment: if I unprotected the pdf will the print option still be disabled? and PDFSharp is old, is this library still updated?.

Comment: @Mark Yu - Development has stabilized, but support is still available at pdfsharp.net. I found this link that might help you: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2085&hilit=password